# How to terminate a remote Eclipse debug on java

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am remote debugging a java application and it genrally works well. However, I am coding something new and now I get to a line and I want to terminate the program. But the only buttons available are suspend and disconnect. Suspend of course, does not terminate, and disconnect stops the debug but leaves the remote app in a whatever state where I then have to restart it.

There is a terminate button - but it is always greyed out. How can I choose to kill a program from Eclipse debugger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you forget to allow remote termination of the VM when you configured Eclipse?

[image: termination]

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Eclipse Juno ? I am experiencing same thing even if the termination of remote VM is enabled as suggested, in such a case you could switch to Debug perspective to kill the remove VM.