# Unable to start Java debug remote application

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to start Remote Java application but when I run it in debug mode, it exits silently without any error message for first time and when I debug it again it throws Cannot connect to VM Connection refused error.

How to start debug mode successfully ?

I have started tomcat on port 1045 and connection from eclipse gets established successfully on port 1045

Output of netstat is :

TCP 127.0.0.1:1045 127.0.0.1:53184 Established 14760
TCP 127.0.0.1:53184 127.0.0.1:1045 Established 6996

But eclipse does not start debug mode. What is missing ?

Comment: "connection refused" means no more that port is listened by the process, probably when remote debug exits it kills the remote jvm make sure [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19177827/175554) checkbox unchecked

Comment: How to prevent it from killing JVM ?

Comment: "make sure that checkbox unchecked" click that link :) it shows what checkbox